# Understanding Gradle profile report's order of tasks

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am trying to profile a Gradle build by first building clean and then w/out changing any code, rebuild to see what tasks are not "UP-TO-DATE"

So I run

```
./gradlew --stop
./gradlew clean
./gradlew --profile --offline --rerun-tasks app:assembleDebug
# re-run profile without any code changes
./gradlew --profile --offline app:assembleDebug
```

If everything is configured right, the second profile should show all tasks as UP-TO-DATE. However this is the generated report:

Task    Duration    Result

```
:app    38.615s (total)
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug 29.214s 
:app:kaptDebugKotlin    5.325s  
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  1.401s  
:app:processDebugResources  0.922s  
:app:mergeDebugResources    0.849s  
:app:packageDebug   0.297s  
:app:processDebugManifest   0.217s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugKotlin 0.103s  
:app:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles   0.072s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin   0.071s  
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug   0.041s  
:app:mergeDebugJavaResource 0.034s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugNativeLibs   0.016s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets   0.011s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders    0.008s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateSafeArgsDebug  0.007s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:stripDebugDebugSymbols 0.006s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices 0.003s  
:app:compileDebugAidl   0.002s  NO-SOURCE
:app:extractProguardFiles   0.002s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig   0.002s  UP-TO-DATE
....
```

Are these listed in order of operation? I.e. is `processDebugGoogleServices` the first not up-to-date task. Does that then mean the other not up-to-date tasks are *because* `processDebugGoogleServices` is not up to date?

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle tasks are executed according to their dependencies, and may be executed in parallel if there are no dependent tasks between the application nodes.

The listing shows the order in which the tasks are evaluated.

Later tasks would not necessarily be out of date after `processDebugGoogleServices`, unless they're specifically dependent on that task.

Comment: "The listing shows the order in which the tasks are evaluated." So Gradle starts with the top level task (app:assembleDebug) and then works down the dependency tree?

In general though, from my profile is there any way to determine which task(s) are the offending not up-to-date tasks?

Comment: Other way around - Gradle processes the tasks and starts with the lowest item on the dependency tree and works its way up.  You could always capture the output and remove the UP-TO-DATE lines to find out what it's compiling.

Comment: Right, but some of the not-up-to-date tasks are only not up to date because one or more of their dependencies are also not up to date, right? I mean it's likely that only one of those tasks is the problem, and then its propagating to all other tasks that depend on the offender.

Comment: Ahh i just used --scan instead of --profile and got a much better result. Using the generated html page I see `The task was not up-to-date because of the following reasons: Input property 'inputResourcesDir' file example/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values_values.arsc.flat has changed.`